# Working with lists in R: say no to for loops?

Tags: r, list

I would like to find a better way to collapse a list into a dataframe based on a logical function in R. Here's a reproducible example of what worked for me:

```
a <- data.frame(foo = c(1:3), bar = c(letters[1:3]))
bazL <- list(c("a", "z", "g"), NULL, "c")

a$baz <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(a$foo)) {
  a$baz[i] <- (bazL[[i]] > 0)[1]
}
```

In my use case, each list item corresponded to a dataframe row. I wanted to know whether the corresponding list item was empty or not. I'm sure there's a better way than the approach above.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Filter` to filter out the NULL elements in `list`

```
Filter(Negate(is.null), bazL)
```

---

Or for getting a logical vector

```
lengths(bazL)>0
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Simple and effective. I didn't test the filter function, but wouldn't that be the same as unlist?

Comment: @Simon If you use `unlist` on a `list` of `vector`s, it changes it ta single `vector`.  The `Filter` is applied on a `data.frame` or `list` to remove the individual components i.e. columns or list elements based on the function condition

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `is.null` to check if each list item is empty or not

```
#a$baz = 
!sapply(bazL, is.null)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Nice answer. This will generalise nicely for other work I'll di on lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `map` function provided by the `purrr` package. For example,

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

a <- mutate(a, baz = map(bazL, ~ !is.null(.x)))
```

Here `map` takes in `bazL` as the list it iterates over (be careful though, if the dataframe `a` has a column named `bazL`, `mutate` will think you are referring to that `bazL`, not the globally defined one), and applies the `is.null` function to each element of `bazL`, then negates with `!`. The `.x` is just a placeholder here for each element of `bazL` and we use the formula interface.

Comment: Very nice use of the purr package.